Continuous structure preserved under homeomorphic topological spaces?
The title seems rather vague, but I was unsure what else to call it. So, sorry about that :)
Problem: Let $f:(X,\tau_X)\to (Y,\tau_Y)$ be a continuous map. Say, $(X,\tau_X')\neq (X,\tau_X)$ are homeomorphic and $(Y,\tau_Y')\neq (Y,\tau_Y)$ are homeomorphic. Then, is $f:(X,\tau_X')\to (Y,\tau_Y')$ (the underlying set maps being the same) necessarily continuous?
I have tried to construct a square with the two $f$'s (say $f_1$, $f_2$) and the two homeomorphisms (say $h,g$), but I am unable to show that the square commutes. If it did, I would have that $f_2=hfg^{-1}$ which is continuous.
Similarly, what about the situation where topological spaces are replaced by smooth manifolds, continuous maps by smooth maps and homeomorphisms by diffeomorphisms? I seem to have shown the following in one of the exercises I am solving from Lee (Intro to Smooth Manifolds), which, if correct, says that the answer to this question is no in the category of smooth manifolds:
Consider the smooth structure on $\mathbb R$ given by the global chart $(\mathbb R,x\mapsto x/(|x|)$ (call this smooth manifold $\mathbb R_2$). I have shown that this is not the same smooth structure on $\mathbb R$ as the one given by $(\mathbb R,x\mapsto x)$ (call this smooth manifold $\mathbb R_1$). Note, $x\mapsto x/(|x|):\mathbb R_2\to \mathbb R_1$ is a diffeomorphism since the co-ordinate representation is identity. However, $x\mapsto x/(|x|):\mathbb R_1\to \mathbb R_1$ is not a diffeomorphism since it is not differentiable at $0$, despite $\mathbb R_s\simeq \mathbb R_1$.

Wait, you have $(Y,\tau_{Y})$ and $(X,\tau_Y)?$ The only way for $X$ and $Y$ to have the same topology is if $X=Y.$

Oops typo, corrected now.

Let $\tau$ and $\tau'$ be two topologies on the same set $X$ with $\tau \neq \tau'$ but $(X,\tau)$ homeomorphic to $(X,\tau')$. This means that there is some open set $U\in \tau$ that is not open in $\tau'$ (or vise versa). Consequentially $id_X: (X,\tau')\rightarrow (X, \tau)$ is not continuous since $id_X^{-1}(U) = U$ is not open. So we have the example of a continuous map $id_X: (X,\tau')\rightarrow (X, \tau')$ such that the induced map $id_X:(X,\tau)\rightarrow (X, \tau')$ is not continuous, even though the spaces are homeomorphic.

Thank you Daniel :))
